# Java IO - Print the output of a recursive function from the console to a .txt file

Tags: java, recursion, io

I have this code where I recursively list all the files from a folder. My question is how to print the output from the console to a .txt file? It would help me a lot if someone could add what is needed in my code.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Exp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File f = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads");
        rec(f);
    }

    public static void rec(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File[] list = file.listFiles();

        for (File f : list) {
            if (f.isFile()) {
                System.out.println(f.getName());
            }

            else if (f.isDirectory()) {
                rec(f);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a file and write to it in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-do-i-create-a-file-and-write-to-it-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently outputting to `System.out`, which is a `PrintStream`. Instead of doing that, create a `PrintStream` for a .txt file and pass the PrintStream as an argument to your `rec` method. Use the *try-with-resources* idiom to ensure the PrintStream gets closed when you're done with it.